# Possible AllowedOAuthScopes value?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-js

I want to add resource server to `AllowedOAuthScopes` of `CreateUserPoolClientRequest` param. AWS docs said [image] below, without mentioning what the value of resource server look like.

The resource server identifier is `homes` with permission is `read` and `*`. I've tried `homes/read` and `homes/*` and got `InvalidOAuthFlowException`.

Answer (score 1):

The `AllowedOAuthScopes` was correct. It was `CallbackURLs` that I didn't set correctly!

Just in case anyone came across this, to use resource server:

```
AllowedOAuthFlows: ["code"],
AllowedOAuthFlowsUserPoolClient: true,
AllowedOAuthScopes: ["homes/read", "homes/*"],
CallbackURLs: ["https://example.com"],
```